# ycsb for mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, benchmarking, ycsb, nosql

I'm trying to benchmark locally running instance of mongoDB using YCSB. I'm getting the following exception while inserting the load:

```
YCSB Client 0.1
Command line: -db com.yahoo.ycsb.db.MongoDbClient -s -P workloads/workloada -load
Loading workload...
Starting test.
Could not initialize MongoDB connection pool for Loader: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.MongoDbClient.init(MongoDbClient.java:78)
    at com.yahoo.ycsb.DBWrapper.init(DBWrapper.java:63)
    at com.yahoo.ycsb.ClientThread.run(Client.java:189)
java.lang.NullPointerException
[OVERALL], RunTime(ms), 5.0
[OVERALL], Throughput(ops/sec), 0.0
```

The command is as follows:

```
./bin/ycsb load mongodb -s -P workloads/workloada
```

I'm running it on Rhel 6.1 and using out of box ycsb 0.1.4.

Comment: Looks like perhaps you don't have a local MongoDB instance running, or the Java client is unable to connect.  Did you follow the config instructions in [YCSB/mongodb](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/tree/master/mongodb)?

Answer (score 3):

I also got this error when I was running from the ycsb archive that is linked to from the README. I verified that mongo was up and that other clients could connect to the database. So on a lark, I decided to clone the github repo, build from source and was pleasantly surprised when everything worked.